# Create a regular expression with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to create a regular expression for below string.
The dynamic portion (i.e. for which expression needed is in bold text)

---

The mail system

```
**email address**: host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152] said:
550 Requested action not taken:
**mailbox unavailable** (in reply to RCPTTO command)
```

---

Basically I want that my regexp search for email and the "mailbox unavailable".

So it will search for mail first and then search for the string "mailbox unavailable".

How can I do this? I need to use preg_match php function for this.

---

**Edit:**

Actually I am doing code to find the bounced mail. I am placing the source code of the full email to match. one of my email giving above error. So I need to check for that error contain in email code or not. If that code found then it will return error accordingly. So in that error message dynamic parts are email address, ip in square brackets and the string mailbox unavailable.

Comment: this question lacks clarity and direction. which parts of the string is "static" (not changing) and which parts are "dynamic" (changes every time)?

Comment: I need regex which find the email with surrounded in <> and then after find the string "mailbox unavailable". hope clear now.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do, but it's 'preg_match' not 'prag_match'

Comment: not clear. u made it more confusing. nothing in the string you provided contains `<>` ! edit your question. don't add to the comments.

Comment: you want the regex string for preg_match to test whether or not the email is returned with mailbox unavailable?  sounds do-able, but id guess theres a better email-specific function (i dont know such a function but it seems likely)

Answer (score 0):

The regex for e-mail address alone should give you an idea of the complexity of what you're trying to achieve:

http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use those expressions:

```
preg_match("/[<]\S+@\S+[>]/i",$your_string); // this matches: <info@example.com>

preg_match("/mailbox unavailable/i",$your_string) // this matches: mailbox unavailable
```

The i after the last slash stands for case insensitive.